# How make a vector of neighbor words?

Tags: python

I am working on a NLP program. I want to make a vector for every word to show its four surrounding neighbor as far as possible. For example, we have a sentence: `I go to school every day`. The vector for word `school` is as follows: `V = [go, to, every, day]`. This was the simple condition and i am able to do it. But when it comes to words located in the first or end of the sentence, it does not give me the desired results. For example, for word `I` the vector should be like this: `V=[0,0,go,to]` but the output is this:`[go,to]` or for word `go` vector should be: `[0,I,to,school]`.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
xx=[contains some words]
for text in sentences:
        text = text.lower().split()
        for i in range(len(text)):
            token = text[i]
            if(token not in xx):

                n1 = text[i-2 : i]
                n2 = text[i+1: i+1+window_size]
                print(n1,n2,n1+n2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully, this helps, I am just checking if I have enough words on left and right!

```
def get_surrounding(sentence='', word='', window_size=4):
    l,r=sentence.split(word)[:2]
    l=l.strip().split()[-window_size//2:]
    r=r.strip().split()[:window_size//2]
    l=['0']*(window_size//2-len(l))+l
    r=r+['0']*(window_size//2-len(r))
    return l+r
s = 'I go to school every day'
print(get_surrounding(sentence=s, word='I', window_size=4))
print(get_surrounding(sentence=s, word='go', window_size=4))
print(get_surrounding(sentence=s, word='to', window_size=4))
print(get_surrounding(sentence=s, word='school', window_size=4))
print(get_surrounding(sentence=s, word='every', window_size=4))
print(get_surrounding(sentence=s, word='day', window_size=4))
```

```
['0', '0', 'go', 'to']
['0', 'I', 'to', 'school']
['I', 'go', 'school', 'every']
['go', 'to', 'every', 'day']
['to', 'school', 'day', '0']
['school', 'every', '0', '0']
```

Comment: I am very thankful of you. it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can always preprocess the data to suit your needs.

```
sentence = 'i go to school every day'

def get_neighbors(sentence, num_neighbors):
    # Preprocess sentence and fill margins with defaults
    default = 0
    words = [word.strip() for word in sentence.split(' ')]
    total_words = len(words)
    margin = num_neighbors // 2
    for x in range(margin):
        words.insert(0, default)
        words.append(default)

    ans = []
    for i, word in enumerate(words[2:-2]):
        i += margin
        neighbours = [words[i-2], words[i-1], words[i+1], words[i+2]]
        ans.append(neighbours)
    return ans


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(sentence)
    print(get_neighbors(sentence, 4))

user@Inspiron:~/code/general$ python get_neighbors.py 
i go to school every day
[[0, 0, 'go', 'to'], [0, 'i', 'to', 'school'], ['i', 'go', 'school', 'every'], ['go', 'to', 'every', 'day'], ['to', 'school', 'day', 0], ['school', 'every', 0, 0]]
user@Inspiron:~/code/general$
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete answer. this code is very useful for my problem. thank you